# Listen To All Button Presses In My Activity (With Activity argument only)

Tags: android, button, view, android-activity

Is it possible to write a function that only gets Activity in its arguments and can respond to all buttons pressed in that activity?

I've tried registering something through ViewTreeObserver and maybe use decorView but no success.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You have to find all of your buttons and set their onClickListeners to same listener. Either you can make your activity implement View.OnClickListener or you can create a listener object by implementing it.

Knowing the root layout of your activity, you can access children views by [getChildAt(index)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29). Of course, you should check if a child is a `Button`.

For example in `onCreate` you can do it by:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // a layout is a ViewGroup
    ViewGroup mainLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
        if (view instanceof Button) {
            view.setOnClickListener(listener);
        }
    }
}
```

The trick here is to find all the buttons even if they are children of sub layouts. For this purpose, you must write a recursive function like this:

```
private void setListenerToAllButtons(ViewGroup viewGroup, View.OnClickListener listener) {

    for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view;
            setListenerToAllButtons(group, listener);
        } else if (view instanceof Button) {
            view.setOnClickListener(listener);
        }
    }
}
```

then use it like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewGroup mainLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        setListenerToAllButtons(mainLayout, this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your Activity must

```
implements OnClicklistener
```

and have the method

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface di, int which) {

}
```

then you can

```
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

The onClick method will be called whenever any button is clicked (if you have set `this` as listener).
The `int which` argument is the id of the button pressed.

EDIT: I think I got your question wrong :-/

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible. The idea is:

- You define an interface inside that Activity. For example:

  public interface listener{
          public void method(Activity activity);
      }
- In your activity you should expose a register method which registers the listeners.

  public void setListener(Listener listener)
  {
         this.listener=listener;
  }
- Whenever any Button press/click event occurs, call the interface method from the Activity.

  exampleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  ```
          @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                 listener.listenToButton(this);
                      }
  ```
- Now any Class implements the listener interface has to implement the `listenToButton(Activity activity)` method and this way they will get the reference to the Activity at any Button press(or click) event